# Java extending and implementing interface

Tags: java, interface

Class A implements interface1 ,interface2 {}   Class B extends A{}  ....   Can I implement methods of interface1 and interface2 from class B?

Comment: For these kind of questions you should always just try it first, then think about the experiment. Then maybe ask.

Comment: I have a question. In class A have you implement all  the method of the interface 1 and 2? If yes, in class B you are doing polymorphism because you are overriding the behavior of your parent class. If not, you have to make your class A abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but A must implement them too or be declared abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement the methods but at first declare abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Actually, that is what all about "**Inheritance**" in **OOPS principle**.

***Scenario 1:***

You haven't implemented methods of interface1 & interface2 in class A then you are supposed to declare the methods(of the interfaces) as ***abstract*** so that the Child classes of the same(i.e. class A) can implement those methods.

***Scenario 2:***

You have implemented methods of both the interfaces viz. 1 & 2 then you can freely ***override*** all the methods(of the interfaces) in the child class of A, in this scenario, which is class B.